How to build sqlite3 for windows on Linux for cross platform build of electron app using electronuserland/builder:wine
build-win:
  stage: build-win
  image: electronuserland/builder:wine
  script:    
    - npm install
    - npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source --runtime=node-webkit --target_arch=ia32
    - APP_VERSION=$(node -p "require('./package.json').version")
    - 'echo "APP_VERSION: $APP_VERSION"'
    - |
      if [[ $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master" ]]; then
        CMD_STRING="npm run build-win:prod"
      elif [[ $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "dev" ]]; then
        CMD_STRING="npm run build-win:dev"
      else
        CMD_STRING="npm run build-win:dev"
      fi
    - 'echo "Building for branch: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"'
    - wine cmd /c "$CMD_STRING" # Use wine cmd /c to correctly interpret the command string
    - ls build/
  variables:
    ELECTRON_CACHE: "/root/.cache/electron"
    ELECTRON_BUILDER_CACHE: "/root/.cache/electron-builder"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/
    exclude:
      - build/win-unpacked/** # Exclude unpacked Linux build
  only:
    - master
    - dev
    - Pre-dev

above is the build stage of my gitlab-ci.yml that is supposed to build windows version of my app, but the exe generated throws error that node_modules/lib/ is not found. I am unable to find any standard solution for these scenarios. I am trying to use dockur/windows and also trying to install node on wine and then install sqlite3 again. Please let me know whats the way out. thank you.
